# discord.py - How can I have 2 arguments in a command?

Tags: python, discord.py

just wondering how an I have 2 arguments, for example

```
User: ?text A B
Bot: A B
```

Like "arg1" and "arg2" Example:

```
await bot.say({} {}.format(arg1, arg2))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For 2 args as 2 separate variables you could do something like [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#positional)

```
@bot.command()
async def args(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await ctx.send('You sent {} and {}'.format(arg1, arg2))
```

Or if you want to send all args passed as a list you could do... [as per the rewrite documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#variable):

```
@bot.command()
async def args(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send('`{}` arguments: `{}`'.format(len(args), ', '.join(args)))
```

Or if you want to send everything as one argument you could do ([documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)):

```
@bot.command()
async def args(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: I'm a little late, but can you provide the documentation regarding the solution above, so I can look into it further? - nvm I found it.